# Declaring an int and iterating it by 1 from within two for loops

Tags: java

I have an int (counter), two lists and two for loops. For each iteration of loop 1 loop 2 iterates 4 times. Each of the 4 times, a shape is created and it's ID is set to that of list2.get(counter); This works fine if the counter is set to 0 but breaks if counter is set to 1. the lists are both observable lists but i want the first value pulled from list 2 to be the second value.

I've tried a number of things and nothing has worked so any help on this is much appreciated. please let me know if I need to be clearer with my explanation. Code is below.

THANKS!

```
int count = 1;
String unit;

for(Object h:hours){

    VBox timesheetHour = new VBox();

    Label lbl = new Label(h.toString());
    lbl.getStyleClass().add("timesheetHour");
    timesheetHour.getChildren().add(lbl);

    HBox timesheetSlots = new HBox();
    timesheetSlots.setSpacing(5);


    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){

        unit = hourUnits.get(count);

        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(20, 25);
        r.getStyleClass().add("timesheetSlot");
        r.setId(unit);

        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to explain how it "breaks"

Comment: I have this code within the initialize method on the home window in a javafx application. if int count is set to one, the home window just won't open after the login screen. if int count is set to 0 everything works fine.

Comment: Aris2World I don't understand what you mean by zero based? I'm new to java so I apologise in advance. If I manually set unit = hourUnits.get(1); it works but then ofc doesn't iterated to get the rest of the values I need.

Comment: @ace perhaps your list doesn't have enough elements and you get IndexOutOfBoundsException when you start from index 1.

Comment: @Ace Zero based means you start counting from 0. The first element of the list will be at index 0, the second element at index 1, and so on.

Comment: Ok I understand but I need the element at index 1 to be the first value thats pulled from the list. the list contains 96 elements @Eran. Honestly what I'm more interesting in understanding now is why my code doesn't work rather than finding a quick fix for it

Comment: Please update your question, instead of putting infos in comments.

Comment: @ace you have to make sure you don't call `hourUnits.get(count)` for `count>=hourUnits.size()`.

Comment: @Ace These comments are telling you what (most likely) the problem is. No "quick fixes" are offered. Pay attention. Also, learn to use exception handling to catch errors like this one.

Comment: @Eran hourUnits gets populated in the initialize method from the database with 96 records. hourUnits has 96 elements in it. count cannot be >= hourUnits.size()

Comment: @Ace That depends on the number of elements in `hours`. if `hours.size()>=96/4`, count will reach 96

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work because with starting counter value of 0 it tries to `get` elements with indexes from 0 to 95 (and its OK), but with starting counter value of 1 it uses indexes from 1 to 96. But an array with 96 elements does not contain an element with index 96, therefore your code fails on this last step.

If you want just to ignore the very first element, you can add this logic in the inner cycle:

```
int counter = 0;
...
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++){
        if (count > 0) {
            unit = hourUnits.get(count);

            Rectangle r = new Rectangle(20, 25);
            r.getStyleClass().add("timesheetSlot");
            r.setId(unit);
        }
        count++;
    }
```

It may be not what you want exactly, but if this is the case, you should clarify the exact task.

Comment: this explains a lot and makes sense... thank you for your time and help it is much appreciated. you've almost fixed my issue but you've given me a lot to play around with to get exactly how i want.